# How do I style the new 'Ctrl + Scroll" fade in that overlays on the Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps

as most of you who use the Google Maps API would be aware, there's the new feature which requires the ⌘ key on Macs and the Ctrl key on Windows to be held down to enable scrolling.

The feature has now grown on me a bit and I've decided not to disable it, but the dark opacity overlay with the text in the middle is a bit overbearing and not very user friendly as the map is basically useless until it disappears.

['Click here to view example image of map overlay'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP6JN.png)

My question is, am I able to style this in any way?  I'd ultimately like to get rid of the text and the overlay altogether, or just the overlay, or just make the overlay surround the text with a small margin like a text box.  Is any of this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you find a solution to this? I'm trying to change the text, which only seems possible by catching and overwriting the event handling of Maps API.